# How to create dlt streaming live table using python in databricks

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I have created a streaming live table using sql as below:

```
CREATE STREAMING LIVE TABLE customers_count_streaming
COMMENT "count of customers"
TBLPROPERTIES ("myCompanyPipeline.quality" = "gold")
AS
SELECT count(*) as customers_count
FROM STREAM(LIVE.customers_cleaned)
```

How can I create exact same table but using python @dlt in databricks

Answer (score 0):

You just use `@dlt.table` in combination with `dlt.read_stream`, something like that (but I'm not sure if `count(*)` makes sense as you need to partition data by some window, etc.):

```py
@dlt.table
def customers_count_streaming():
  df = dlt.read_stream("customers_cleaned")
  return some_transformation(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import dlt       
    @dlt.table(
    COMMENT = "count of customers",
    TBLPROPERTIES= ("myCompanyPipeline.quality":"gold")
    )
    def customers_count_streaming():
        dlt.read_stream("customers_cleaned").selectExpr("count(*) 
        as customers_count")
```

I have referred this document https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/tutorial-python.html, but here it is not reading from streaming table. To  read from streaming live table in python, you have to use dlt.read_stream